# Почему элементы массива $_SESSION не были установлены?

Tags: php, form, сессия

Есть 3 файла: session_form.html, session_set.php, session_get.php

session_form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="entry" action="session_set.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Введите имя пользователя и пароль. В имени пользователя используйте только буквы, а в пароле только буквы и цифры.</legend>
            Имя пользователя: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
            Пароль: <input type="password" name="pass"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Авторизоваться">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

session_set

```
<?php 
 function reject($entry) {
     echo "Недопустимо: $entry.<br>";
     echo 'Пожалуйста, <a href="session_form.html">авторизуйтесь</a><br>';
 }

 if (isset($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"])) {
     $user = trim($_POST["user"]);
     $pass = trim($_POST["pass"]);

     if (!ctype_alpha($user)) {
         reject("имя пользователя");
         $user = null;
     }

     if (!ctype_alnum($pass)) {
         reject("пароль");
         $pass = null;
     }

     if ($user != null && $pass != null) {
         $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
         $_SESSION["pass"] = $pass;
         header("Location: session_get.php");
     }
 }
 else {
     header("Location: session_form.html");
 }
```

session_get

```
<?php
 if (isset($_SESSION["user"])) {
     $user = $_SESSION["user"];
     echo "$user, вы успешно авторизовались.<hr>";
     echo '<a href="session_data.php">Просмотреть данные сессии</a>';
 }
 else {
     echo 'Пожалуйста, <a href="session_form.html">авторизуйтесь</a>';
 }
```

Выводится: Пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь. Почему, если $_SESSION["user"] был установлен в файле session_set.php

Comment: `session_start ` используйте для начала сессии.. вы же её вообще не открываете

Comment: Мда... Как я мог забыть

Comment: Спасибо, можете отправить ответ, и я помечу как решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забываем запускать сессию `session_start()` перед началом работы с ней же.